# Is there a way that I can list the games I own which give out a CD key?

Tags: steam

Some games in Steam give out a CD key when you launch them (or when you hit the CD key button).

I want to backup my CD keys in Steam, so instead of clicking all my games and seeing if they have a CD key, I'm wondering if there is a way that I can list my games which give me a CD key, so I have to only click them.

[image: Sample picture of the screen]

Is there a feature of Steam or a website which is able to show which games of mine give out a CD key?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  A note, though: Of over 2000 games I own on Steam, probably about 10% of those Steam has told me 'this game requires this CD key...'.  However, only about 5 times has the game _actually_ required that key for anything... and all of those were 'Windows Live for Games' games, which no longer exists.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - Is there a practical reason why you would want to backup the CD keys?

Comment: @Chippies No real reason except than backing up.

Comment: Steam saves it, it shows it to you when you launch the game as shown in your screenshot? why do you need another backup?

Comment: @Aequitas just in case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible through Steam, and there are no third-party tools either, but [I believe] it could be done because it seems that the data about whether or not an app has a third-party key is stored in part of the Steam client configuration (along with almost everything else Steam knows about each app). That part of the data is not easily accessible though as it is not stored in an easily-human-readable format (it's a special binary format of Valve's own making), but there are still at least a couple parsers out there that can manage it [namely built with NodeJS].

If you're still interested in this I could probably have something within a few days -- just about to go on a camping trip, so will be away from PC for at least two. An app would be able to automate the process to the point where what keys it can't find it would be able to list the names of so that you could then try to launch those through Steam to get the key(s). Could also give the ability to launch the apps of course, but that would kinda be overkill although it wouldn't take much to add it.